# react-native unlink library error. 'Cannot read property 'find' of undefined

Tags: react-native, npm

I am playing with an ejected Android - React Native app and I was trying to achieve firebase on the platform. So I installed `react-native-firebase` package and it linked iOS successfully but I've got some error then on linking. So now I want to unlink the library but I got some errors like below.

```
rnpm-install info Unlinking react-native-firebase ios dependency 
rnpm-install ERR! It seems something went wrong while unlinking. Error: Cannot read property 'find' of undefined


Cannot read property 'find' of undefined

TypeError: Cannot read property 'find' of undefined
    at removeFromProjectReferences (/Users/fiyuu/riders-react-native/node_modules/react-native/local-cli/link/ios/removeFromProjectReferences.js:23:47)
    at removeProjectFromProject (/Users/fiyuu/riders-react-native/node_modules/react-native/local-cli/link/ios/removeProjectFromProject.js:26:16)
    at unregisterNativeModule (/Users/fiyuu/riders-react-native/node_modules/react-native/local-cli/link/ios/unregisterNativeModule.js:44:10)
    at Object.unregisterNativeModule [as unregister] (/Users/fiyuu/riders-react-native/node_modules/react-native/local-cli/link/ios/common/unregisterNativeModule.js:19:1)
    at /Users/fiyuu/riders-react-native/node_modules/react-native/local-cli/link/unlink.js:57:12
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at unlinkDependency (/Users/fiyuu/riders-react-native/node_modules/react-native/local-cli/link/unlink.js:31:28)
    at tasks (/Users/fiyuu/riders-react-native/node_modules/react-native/local-cli/link/unlink.js:115:1)
```

I've not figured out what is going on with the library. 
I can share any manifest or gradle file if it help to solve problem.

Thanks,

Comment: Have you checked that your node version is compatible with your version of he react-native-cli? (Usually it should show an error because of version incompatibillity but it's one of the usual places which lead to errory)